# MS Data protection manager restore files from linux vhdx

Tags: centos, hyper-v, vss, scdpm

We are backing up our few linux VM servers (Centos 6.6 with VSS , Online backup) in Hyper-V 2012 R2 with Microsoft Data Protection Manager 2012 R2. Its backing with Online method.

In Windows VMs inside restore im able to click trough vhdx and its filesystem and restore files and directories.

But this doesnt count for Linux VMs. Is there way how to restore just some files from that vhdx in restore operation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to mount the VHD in an OS that can parse the file system used by your Linux systems.  This is probably most easily done by using another Linux VM.  Attach a copy of the archived VHD and it will be able to mount the file system.

Comment: Ok, i tought there will be faster option :)